# C# Adding Items To A Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I built a little console application in C# and need to add a windows form interface to it.  I added a form item, and now have a blank form.  I don't know how to go from here and start adding buttons and menus to the form.

Is there a form design toolbar or do I have to add buttons and menus using code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose Toolbox from the View menu..

Comment: After adding the form, how do I interact with it in non-design view?

Comment: Right-click on the form and choose "View Code". To get back, right-click on the code and choose "View Designer"

Answer (score 0):

Click View>Other Toolbars>Toolbox to show the toolbox containing common controls for Windows forms.